# Can't execute javascript inside ajax loaded div

Tags: javascript, jquery-tabs

I'm using ajax to load some content inside a div, and this includes the jQueryVericalTabs plugin.  However the styles won't work an I just see the unformatted text.

With FF's web developer tool I see that the rendered source is not linking to the styles on my CSS file despite being correctly called on the index page.  I tried writing the CSS directly on index.php, on the content file, putting it inside the body tags, with and without the javascript (per plugin's demo), and also the suggestion on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758158/css-problem-within-loaded-div-with-ajax) but none worked, don't know what else to try.  Here's what my header looks like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-jvert-tabs-1.1.4.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-jvert-tabs-1.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(function(){
            $("#accordion").accordion({
                active: false,
                autoHeight: false,
                collapsible: true
            });
        });

    $("#vtabs5").jVertTabs({
        equalHeights: true
    });
    // add click events for open tab buttons
    $("input[id^=openTab]").each(function(index){
        $(this).click(function(){
            openTab("#vtabs6",index);
            return false;
        });
    }); 
    function openTab(tabId,index){
        $(tabId).jVertTabs('selected',index);
    }
});
```

I tried a different plugin, verticalTabs, and the tab-titles show with the correct formatting, but no tab-content is displayed.  I'd still prefer to use the first plugin though, the HTML is a lot cleaner.

I appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply.  I solved it with the suggestion from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317080/jquery-ajax-load-java-script-not-executing), in case someone finds it useful :)

Answer (score 1):

Its just a suggestion, i have never tried it, but according to the jquery documentations, you can achieve and handle ajax loaded contents using `.live()` event. [Check the documentation here.](http://api.jquery.com/live/) Hope it helps and if you get an answer, please post it back

Comment: I know this is an old question/answer, but `.live()` was deprecated on jQuery 1.7, around half year after your answer, and it was definitely removed on 1.9. Use `.on()` instead.